# Basic client/server programming

Tags: language-agnostic, network-programming, client-server

I am new to web programming...I have been asked to create a simple Internet search application which would allow transmit to the browser some data stored remotely in the server. 
Considering the client/server architecture (which I am new to) I would like to know if the "client" is represented only by the Internet browser and therefore the entire code of the web application should be stored in the server. As it's a very generic question a generic answer is also well accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, this is a very generic and broad question.  You'd be well-served by more complete requirements.  Regardless:

Client/server architecture generally means that some work is done by the client, and some by the server.  The client may be a custom application (such as iTunes or Outlook), or it might be a web browser.  Even if it's a web browser, you typically still have some code executing client-side, Javascript usually, to do things like field validation (are all fields filled out?).

Much of the code, as you note, will be running on the server, and some of this may duplicate your client-side code.  Validation, for instance, should be performed on the client-side, to improve performance (no need to communicate with the server to determine if the password meets length requirements), but should be performed on the server as well, since client-side code is easily bypassed.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can put all the code on the server, and have it generate HTML to send back to the browser. Or you can include JavaScript in the HTML pages, so some of the logic runs inside the browser. Many web applications mix the two techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with all the code stored on the server.
1)The user will navigate to a page on your webserver using an url you provide.
2)When the webserver gets the request for that page, instead of just returning a standard html file, it will run your code, perhaps some PHP, which inserts the server information, perhaps from a database, into a html template.
3) The resulting fully complete html file is sent to the client. To the client's browser, it looks like any other html page.

For an example of PHP the dynamically inserts information into HTML see: (this wont be exactly what you will do but it will give you an idea of how PHP can work)
code:
http://www.php-scripts.com/php_diary/example1.phps
see the result (refresh a few times to see it in action):
http://www.php-scripts.com/php_diary/example1.php3

You can see from this the "code file" looks just like a normal html file, except what is between angled brackets is actually PHP code, in this case it puts the time into the position it is at in the html file, in your case you would write code to pull the data you want into the file.